# Summing the values of one column only up to the depth of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have rows 1:*m* populated with values in column A, and in column B I have rows 1:*n* populated with values, where *n* < *m*. How can I find the sum of values in column A from row 1 up to row *n*.

In other words, how can I sum the values in Column A down to the last row of data in Column B where both Columns may have more values added to new rows at any time.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment on the answer, will you have any blank cells in column B? If so, would you want the total of A 1:n or the total of A's cells where B's cells are not blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: To ignore text values**

`=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((ROW(A:A)<=MAX(IF(B:B<>"",ROW(B:B))))*A:A,0))`

This will produce a 0 value when an error occurs so the formula behaves for values only.

***Original Answer:***

In addition to the other answer -

**If you are looking for total of A where B has a value then:**

`=SUMIF(B:B,"<>",A:A)`

This is pretty self explanitory, =SUMIF(range,criteria,[sum_range]) we check B:B for non blanks and then sum the corresponding cells from A:A.

**If you are looking for total of A1:A*n* where *n* is the last row with a value from column B then:**

This will need to be entered as an array formula (when in the formula bar hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
`=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(A:A)<=MAX(IF(B:B<>"",ROW(B:B))))*A:A)`

Array formula's break down ranges and caluclate them them one cell (or row) at a time. The MAX rows is broken down as an array, the IF sormula is returning 0 for false (default) and the row number for true so MAX is then grabbing the highest row number from the array (18 in the below example).

The Sumproduct formula is then producing true/false (1 or 0) for each cell in A:A where the row is less than or equal to the MAX row of non blank entries in B:B.

The formula then multiplies the true/false results (0 or 1) by the value in the corresponding A:A cell thus when the condition is met we have 1 x the value being summed and when the condition is not met then 0 will be summed (0 x the value).

I hope this helps explain the logic, feel free to probe my brain for more of an explanation if not.

[image]

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for as I never mentioned that B does not have to contain a value in every cell. However, the formula is still not working for me - I think it is because the values of A are calculated using a formula in each cell of A. Would this effect your formula?

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'll test it out with some fomulated values and see what might be the issue.

Comment: Possibly text values from the title row, try changing the formula to A2:Am and make the ranges match across the formula

Comment: Update for text values made

Comment: If it still doesn't work try changing the `MAX(IF(B:B<>"",` to `MAX(IF(LEN(B:B)>0,` as `<>""` sometimes still pulls formulated cells.

Comment: The formula to ignore text values works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following formula dynamically determines the row of the last entry in column B and sums the values in column A up to this row.

```
=SUM(A1:INDIRECT("A"&COUNTA(B:B)))
```

Comment: Nice approach, but it will only work if column **B** has no missing items.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that in the question. B does contian many empty cells